# while sending parameters to @Query function if i give like ?1 it is trying to excute like ? only

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

when i try send:-

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  labels where personal_ic_id=?1 and content like '%2%'",nativeQuery = true)
List<Labels> searchByLabels(String personalIcId, String key);
```

it has been executing like:-

```
SELECT * FROM  labels where personal_ic_id=? and content like '%?2%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove single inverted comma from like option

Use below

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM  labels where personal_ic_id=?1 and content like %?2%",nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: sir i need same kind of help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804903/other-user-id-parameter-is-not-working-at-execution-time-i-dont-why