# other_user_id parameter is not working at execution time i dont why

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

```
public interface ConnectionsRepository extends CrudRepository<Connections,String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM connections WHERE other_user_id=?1 and acceptance=0 and name like %?2% "
            + " or designation like %?2% "
            + " or entity like %?2% "
            + " or location like %?2%"
            + " or contact1 like %?2%"
            + " or contact2 like %?2%"
            + " or icsnid like %?2%"
            + " or email like %?2%",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Connections> getManagingList(String userId,String keyword, int offset);
```

Comment: its was giving result without considering the other_user_id

Comment: no @Akina it was String

Comment: @Akina in your first comment in native queries no need to make pakkerns in between singlr quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are simply missing `()`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM connections WHERE other_user_id=?1 and acceptance=0 and (name like %?2% "
        + " or designation like %?2% "
        + " or entity like %?2% "
        + " or location like %?2%"
        + " or contact1 like %?2%"
        + " or contact2 like %?2%"
        + " or icsnid like %?2%"
        + " or email like %?2%)",nativeQuery = true)
```

---

there is a diffrence between

```
a && b && c || d
```

and

```
a && b && (c || d)
```